# Incorrect work bootstrapv4 styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I import bootstrap files:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

Add html for links

```
<Link to="/posts/create" className="btn btn-primary">Create</Link>
<Link to="/posts/create" className="btn btn-success">Create</Link>
```

And have that

[image]

Instead that:
[image]

Comment: what kind of import is `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css/js'` ? please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: also let assume it's true where is your rest of code are you sure you don't have any other css or override external css?